# Insert texts into compose body for new meetings using Office Add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I want to append html texts into a composed body for meetings using Outlook Add-In. Something to develop to a template eventually where users can click a single button and the template load into the body of the meeting

Problem seem to be calling the function properly from the manifest.xml file. I'm following the instruction here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/insert-data-in-the-body

I'm calling the function inside the Javascript file but it's not doing anything when I sideload the add-in.

```js
var item;

Office.initialize = function () {
    item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
        // Insert data in the top of the body of the composed 
        // item.
        prependItemBody();
    });
}

// Get the body type of the composed item, and prepend data  
// in the appropriate data type in the item body.
function prependItemBody() {
    item.body.getTypeAsync(
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                write(asyncResult.error.message);
            }
            else {
                // Successfully got the type of item body.
                // Prepend data of the appropriate type in body.
                if (result.value == Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html) {
                    // Body is of HTML type.
                    // Specify HTML in the coercionType parameter
                    // of prependAsync.
                    item.body.prependAsync(
                        '<b>Greetings!</b>',
                        { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, 
                        asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                        function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.status == 
                                Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                write(asyncResult.error.message);
                            }
                            else {
                                // Successfully prepended data in item body.
                                // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                            }
                        });
                }
                else {
                    // Body is of text type. 
                    item.body.prependAsync(
                        'Greetings!',
                        { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text, 
                            asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                        function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.status == 
                                Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                write(asyncResult.error.message);
                            }
                            else {
                                // Successfully prepended data in item body.
                                // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                            }
                         });
                }
            }
        });

}

// Writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
    document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>05f0c002-3399-412c-9b8b-aa13e0ec1cb2</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Company Meeting Template"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A meeting template to organize effective meetings."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>prependItemBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Company Template"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert Meeting Template"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Insert Company Meeting Template into Meeting Body."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/showdown/dist/showdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/urijs/src/URI.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your manifest, you are using `ExecuteFunction`, and you have correctly specified the function name as `prependItemBody`, as well as a FunctionFile. The implementation for `prependItemBody` takes in an `event` argument, which is missing in your code. This links the function directly to the button, so you don't need to call `prependItemBody` inside `Office.initialize`. Clicking on the button will invoke this function for you. Documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile

Comment: Can you make these changes and try to see if it resolves your issue? It is also possible that there is a JavaScript error in your code that could cause the entire script to fail. However, that can only be ascertained after fixing the issues mentioned aboved.